# ServiceStack web services security

Tags: web-services, security, servicestack

Hi I am new to working with Servicestack and have downloaded their very comprehensive bootstrapapi example and am working with it, but am still having some issues. The issue is with security, what is happening is I am getting 405 errors when trying to access the protected services. Using the authenticate service it appears that I am authenticating correctly. Please help and explain.  Here is the code:

```
public class Hello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AuthHello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RoleHello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

The Services:

```
public class HelloService : ServiceBase<Hello> 
{
    //Get's called by all HTTP Verbs (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,etc) and endpoints JSON,XMl,JSV,etc
    protected override object Run(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, Olle är en ÖL ål " + request.Name };
    }
}

[Authenticate()]
public class AuthHelloService : RestServiceBase<AuthHello>
{
    public object Execute(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}

[RequiredRole("Test")]
public class RoleHelloService : RestServiceBase<RoleHello>
{
    public object Execute(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}
```

Here is the AppHost:

```
public class HelloAppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services

        public HelloAppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {

            //Register all Authentication methods you want to enable for this web app.
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
            }));
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient() { FlushOnDispose = false });

            //register user-defined REST-ful urls
            Routes
              .Add<Hello>("/hello")
              .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}")
              .Add<AuthHello>("/AuthHello")
              .Add<RoleHello>("/RoleHello");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Everything works as expect if you replace : RestServiceBase with : ISevice so now the question is why.

Comment: Also I am having a rough time prettifying the code blocks for easy reading and have followed the markdown help but it does not seem to be applying.  <!-- language: c# --> before each code block.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Check the wiki documentation first

I would first go through the documentation in ServiceStack's [Authentication Wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) to get a better idea about how ServiceStack's Authentication works. There's a lot of documentation in the wiki, so if you're unsure of something you should refer to that first. It's a community wiki so feel free to expand whats there if you think it can help others.

#### Refer to the implementation in the source code if behavior is not clear

If you're unsure of what something does you should [refer to the RequiredRole source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/RequiredRoleAttribute.cs) as the master authority as how it works. `RequiredRole` is just a [Request Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) which gets run before every service that has the attribute.

The RequiredRole attribute just calls your `session.HasRole()` method as [seen here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RequiredRoleAttribute.cs#L58-63):

```
public bool HasAllRoles(IAuthSession session)
{
    return this.RequiredRoles
        .All(requiredRole => session != null
            && session.HasRole(requiredRole));
}
```

Because it just calls your session you can override the implementation of `session.HasRole()` if you have a custom session.

#### Registering and Implementing a CustomUserSession

The Social BootstrapApi project does implement its own [CustomSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Models/CustomUserSession.cs) that it [registers here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/AppHost.cs#L195-196) but does not override the `HasRole()` implementation so it uses the built-in implementation in the base [AuthUserSession.HasRole()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthUserSession.cs#L71) which simply looks like the Roles collection to see if the user has the specified role in their Session POCO:

```
public virtual bool HasRole(string role)
{
    return this.Roles != null && this.Roles.Contains(role);
}
```

#### Session properties populated by AuthUserRepository

The **Roles** property (as well as most other properties on a users Session) is populated by the AuthUserRepository that you have specified e.g. if you're using the [OrmLiteAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs) like [SocialBootstrapApi does here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/AppHost.cs#L195-196) than the Roles attribute is persisted in the **Roles** column in the [UserAuth RDBMS table](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/UserAuth.cs#L28). Depending on the AuthUserRepository you use the UserAuth / UserOAuthProvider POCOs get stored as RDBMS tables in OrmLite or as text blobs in Redis, etc.

#### Manage roles and permissions with AssignRoles / UnAssignRoles services

So for a user to have the required role (and authorization to pass), it should have this Role added to its UserAuth db row entry. ServiceStack's [AuthFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AuthFeature.cs) includes 2 services for managing users permissions and roles:

- [/assignroles](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v4-sync/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AssignRolesService.cs)
- [/unassignroles](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v4-sync/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UnAssignRolesService.cs)

#### How to initially give someone the Admin Role

These services does require a [user with the Admin Role](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AssignRolesService.cs#L39) to be already authenticated. 
You can do this by manually changing a specific users **UserAuth.Role** column to include the value "Admin". The Social Bootstrap API project instead does this by handling the `OnAuthenticated()` event on its [CustomUserSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Models/CustomUserSession.cs#L47-55) that simply checks to see if the authenticated username is declared in the Web.Config and if it is, calls the AssignRoles service giving that authenticated user the **Admin** Role:

```
if (AppHost.Config.AdminUserNames.Contains(session.UserAuthName)
    && !session.HasRole(RoleNames.Admin))
{
    var assignRoles = authService.ResolveService<AssignRolesService>();
    assignRoles.Execute(new AssignRoles {
        UserName = session.UserAuthName,
        Roles = { RoleNames.Admin }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt and detailed response! It turns out the issue was actually in the inheritance. When I removed :RestServiceBase and just used :IService for all the services everything worked as expected including the security.  Is there somewhere I can read up on the correct usages because this had me stumped for a day and a half.

Comment: Ideally you should always use ServiceBase / RestServiceBase unless there's a reason you don't want to, e.g. you want to implement your own exception handling. ServiceBase has 1 implementation for all verbs where as RestServiceBase allows you to specify an impl for each verb. Some docs around this: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Your-first-webservice-explained and some more mention about it https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support - Consider expanding the existing docs if you think it can save others time.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that wiki. Answered every question I had and including a couple I had not posted about.  Also, explains why the in my testing the RestServiceBase was not working for me because I was using it incorrectly.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey mythz, what is actually the (practical) difference between roles and permissions? it both seems to be a one to many relationship on the Session?