# is possible to define mi own custom Roles with custom permission with Servicestack?

Tags: servicestack, customization, roles

I'm working on a project with ServiceStack and wondered if it was possible to define a custom Role with custom permissions?

This is because I was reading the [ServiceStack Authentication and authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) and reading the repositories so that I can figure out where and how they implement for example the "CanAccess" permission.

I want to create my own custom "MyPermission" for example and add it to a Role.

Comment: Yes, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/12096813/1295344